# Getting Facebook ID number with API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I know - I have read the documentation - but frankly Facebook is horrible at it. I can't figure out how to send a request that illicits a response. Here's what I'm trying:

```
 NSURL *fbID = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id"];
fbUserID = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: fbID];
```

Where should this code go? Is there a specific class it is looking for if I have set 'self' as delegate?

Comment: Facebook's SDK docs are among the worst ever made in human history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you trying to integrate FB into your app? I have been looking into Facebook connect recently and found their documentation very helpful (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#ios). I know you said you looked at the documentation, but for me after going through their steps for iOS I was able to make an app that allowed users to sign in and give me access to their basic information, including ID. After going through authorization, I had the following code in my app delegate:

```
- (void) fbDidLogin {
    //get information about the currently logged in user
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    NSString *name = [result objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"To prove this works, your name is %@",name];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Thanks for Logging In!" 
                                                    message:msg 
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

This gets the user's full name after logging in and displays it. You can do the same thing for getting their ID.

Comment: Alright I will go back and try again. There were some main points that I thought they did a poor job at explaining, but always wirth another look!

Comment: If you can give more details other than just the code snippet mentioned in the question that would also help. Also, related to your question, setting 'self' as the delegate generally means it should conform to a delegate protocol, so you can check the method definition in the facebook iOS SDK to see which delegate protocol it needs to conform to.